# failing to achive tunneling to fresh ubuntu 10.04 server

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, ssh-tunnel

I've just set up a new 10.04 server and can't get the tunneling to work.

local machine

```
ssh -L 9090:localhost:9090 admin@xxx.xx.xx.xxx
```

login success, but thereafter trying tunnel from local browser, `http://127.0.0.1:9090`

echo at server terminal:

```
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
```

`auth.log`:

```
sshd[24502]: error: connect_to localhost port 9090: failed.
```

`iptables -L`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Trying `9090` at server (`links http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:9090` works)

`sshd_config` is identical to previous 8.04 server, working fine.

What's going on?

Comment: Did you try `telnet localhost 9090`? Also, you mentioned iptables in your question. Did you have any NAT rules? You can paste the output of `iptables -L`.

Comment: telnet over tunnel gives: Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
dump of iptables is in post above. Thanks for help, :-)

Comment: try executing your ssh command with -vvv to get more verbose output, it usually says where something went wrong

Comment: verbose output as answer, sorry for that.. new here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED:

It was a policy issue. At server terminal, requested service at 9090 didn't respond to

```
telnet localhost 9090
```

only at:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 9090
```

Solution was to add this to `/etc/hosts`.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain
```

Answer (score 1):

Verbose output (-vvv).

Login success. Upon request of tunnel from local browser, at server terminal:

```
ebug1: Connection to port 9090 forwarding to localhost port 9090 requested.
debug2: fd 9 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: fd 9 is O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 9 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 3: new [direct-tcpip]
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug2: channel 3: zombie
debug2: channel 3: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 9090 for localhost port 9090,  connect from 127.0.0.1 port 57884, nchannels 4
debug3: channel 3: status: The following connections are open:
  #2 client-session (t4 r0 i0/0 o0/0 fd 6/7 cfd -1)

debug3: channel 3: close_fds r 9 w 9 e -1 c -1
```

Please note that port 9090 replies upon

```
# links 127.0.0.1:9090
```

**ON WORKING MACHINE: (8.04)**

at request:

```
debug1: Connection to port 9090 forwarding to localhost port 9090 requested.
debug2: fd 10 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: fd 10 is O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 10 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 3: new [direct-tcpip]
debug2: channel 3: open confirm rwindow 2097152 rmax 32768
debug2: channel 3: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 3: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 3: obuf empty
debug2: channel 3: close_write
debug2: channel 3: output drain -> closed
```

regards
//t

Comment: For future reference, this should be appended to your original question, not added as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this thread](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/apache-same-ip-two-doc-root-two-ports-and-a-tunnel-302005/) I think the cause of your problem might be Apache, not sshd.
Try changing your Listen directive in your httpd.conf file to

> Listen 127.0.0.1:9090

Restart httpd afterwards and see if that made any difference.